# PDP Endian and bit shifts

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, endianness

When you do a bit shift in PDP endian does this operation take a little bit longer than if you where on a little or big endian system?

The reason I ask this question is because it seems like bits going in all directions on a shift, would be hard for a computer to do.

Any ways I have no way to test this because I don't have access to a PDP endian machine. =(

Comment: If you're talking about the PDP11, that's a 16-bit machine, with 16-bit registers. AFAIR, PDP11-endianness refers to the way 32-bit `long` is laid out in memory, which is not terribly relevant to the shift, which is usually done in registers. A 32-bit shift on a PDP11 will probably look a lot like a 64-bit shift on a 32-bit machine, or a 128-bit shift on a 64-bit machine.

Comment: @dwelch I am not doing anything....this is merely out of curiosity.

Comment: Any bitwise operations work on values, not representation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The middle endian format of the PDP11 comes out of the necessity to emulate 32 bit operations on a 16 bit machine. This is done by first storing the high word, then the low word in memory, even though the PDP11 uses little endian for its data. This causes the weird endianess. Though, in practice there isn't really a performance difference. Left shifting an integer stored in memory by one place is still done in three instructions:

```
mov #var+2,r0 ; load the address of the low word
asl (r0)      ; left shift low word
rol -(r0)     ; left shift high word with carry
```

If `var` was stored in little endian, the code would be similar:

```
mov #var,r0   ; load address of the low word
asl (r0)+     ; left shift low word
rol (r0)      ; left shift high word
```

Comment: I *think* the OP was imagining shifting a PDP-endian 32-bit word in a single operation, and that the hardware to do this would be more complicated than if the bits could just go right-to-left (which is why I focused my answer on that part).  Upvoted for pointing out that PDP-11 is a 16-bit machine and actual code sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Endianness is only observable when you store a word and then look at the bytes separately.

Data in registers on any kind of machine always behaves as binary with the MSB on the left (like you'd write it in a place-value representation like `0b10110101`).  A left shift always multiplies by a power of two, and a right shift is always divides by a power of two, regardless of the machine being big, little, or pdp-endian.

Think of endianness as being applied in the load-store unit of the CPU when executing a load or store wider than one byte.  The registers and execution units part of the core just sees binary integers of register width.

---

It's possible to write ["endian agnostic" code](https://commandcenter.blogspot.ca/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) to serialize integers to/from a stream of bytes without any dependency on the machine's native endianness.  e.g. to extract 4 bytes into an `int`, in this case using little-endian order for the byte stream:

```
i = (data[0]<<0) | (data[1]<<8) | (data[2]<<16) | (data[3]<<24);
```

(This does assume 32-bit `int`, since we don't cast to `uint32_t` before shifting.  And we assume that the 32 bits of file data are 8 per `char`.)

Comment: How is this in any way 'endian agnostic'? It assumes the stream of bytes is stored in little endian order.

Comment: @PaulChilds: it correctly reads little-endian data regardless of the endianness of the C implementation running it.  Without needing any `#ifdef` or conditionally-defined `ntohl` or `le32toh()`

Comment: Yes but on a big endian system it would be rare that you are going to be dealing with little endian data.

Comment: @PaulChilds: you're missing the point.  We're talking about code to read/write your own custom file format, e.g. to serialize and deserialize uint32_t to/from a binary file.  Endian agnostic means you write it once, with no ifdef or helper functions, and your program is compatible with its own file format on any C implementation.  I happened to pick little-endian, but you could just as easily make the serialization format big-endian, or whatever you want.

Comment: And regardless, that last section of my answer exists to make the point that shifts work on data in registers / C variables independently of machine endianness.

Comment: With that clarification, i.e. that you are only deserialising what you serialise, then yes it is endian agnostic, but without it, as your answer has not made clear, it is dangerous to claim it as being "endian agnostic" when a casual reader may try to make use of it e.g. in deserialising a byte stream received over the network.

Answer (score 0):

> Middle-Endian or PDP-Endian systems save the most significant word
>   first, with each word having the least significant byte first. For
>   developers of new software, it is not only perfectly reasonable, but
>   strongly recommended, to ignore this possiblity. I don't think there
>   ever was a processor that stored 32-bit integer values to memory in a
>   middle-endian format, though middle-endianness has occasionally
>   appeared in things like packed-decimal formats, floating point
>   formats, and obscure communications protocols (it's used for the
>   length of TCP/IP packets in Visa's "Visa Base I" protocol).

I think that answers itself.

And when you say shift you mean a bit shift?

Think of it this way, if a processor did support that, then it likely has instructions to do various functions like that.  Some processors only shift one bit out at a time anyway into the carry bit or rotate around.  So it would be irrelevant on those, same speed no matter what.

Likewise with any other.  If you are viewing it and operating on it as bytes you are just making it slow and painful for the sake of making it slow and painful.  But bytes are endianless so it doesnt matter.

You are dealing with words (hopefully), and one of the endiannesses goes away.  But even if every other word word a different endian and you had the ability to read either kind (possible on a number of processors) you still dont care you are still shifting bits around in a word, the endianness goes away at that point as well.

Same web page under myths.

> PDP-11's were "middle-endian". Only sort of. The PDP-11 didn't have
>   instructions to store 32-bit values to memory, so the particular weird
>   "middle-endian" value couldn't possibly apply to the way it stored
>   values in memory. It stored 16-bit values to memory in the usual
>   little endian manner. It could do 32-bit arithmatic, storing the
>   values in pairs of 16-bit CPU registers (not memory). The most
>   signficant word went into the lower numbered register, but within each
>   register values were stored little-endian. So that could be viewed as
>   "middle-endian", but in a sense that could only matter to assembly
>   language programmers and compiler writers, whose code could never hope
>   to be portable anyway.